# Use functions or expressions in Postgres alias names - possible?

Tags: postgresql, alias

Is it possible to use functions or expressions to create an alias name?

For example, is there a way to use `concat` like this?

```
SELECT
  id."myamazingrecords"
FROM
  records AS CONCAT("my", "amazing", "records")
```

I'm looking for a general way to programmatically (via SQL) rename columns in the output of my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an alias has to be a literal.

You can either construct the alias in client code *before* you send the query to the server, or you use a PL/pgSQL function that executes a dynamic query like

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT id."myamazingrecords" FROM records AS %I',
                CONCAT('my', 'amazing', 'records'));
```